# Why is my ui-sref not clickable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to using Angular JS and I am trying to create routers for my app using ui.router.

This is my index.html page where I am injecting other views into it through the  div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>omg</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="" href=""/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/login.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/signup.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="secret">
    <div id="mainBar">
        <div id="mainBarWrapper">
            <div id="siteLogo">
                <img src="images/mimiLogo.png" alt="mimi"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul id="navBar">
                    <li><a ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
                    <li>Sort
                        <ul class="subMenu">
                            <li>thing1</li>
                            <li>thing2</li>
                            <li>thing3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Schools
                        <ul class="subMenu">
                            <li>thing1</li>
                            <li>thing2</li>
                            <li>thing3</li>
                            <li>thing4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Injected View in here-->
    <div ui-view> </div>
</body>
```

This is my index.js file and I've included all the routers here:

```
var app = angular.module('secret', ['ui.router']);

//TO DO: THIS NEEDS TO BE COMPLETED
app.config('$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

//redirect if the router is unspecified
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
//home router where all the posts are displayed
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
})

//the login router
.state('login',{
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'loginController'
});

});

//service to be used by other controllers
app.factory('posts', [function(){
var o = {
    posts:[]
};

    return o;

}]);

//the controller for the login router
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);


//the controller for the post controller
app.controller('postController',['$scope','$stateParams','posts',        function($scope, $stateParams, posts){

}]);

//main controller
app.controller ('mainController', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts){

}]);
```

My index.html and login.html contains some simple html content.
[image]
I am just trying to get the router to work, but for some reason using the sref tag makes me link unclickable. If I use href tag instead and do href="#/login", it gives me a 404 not found error even though I have implemented the .otherwise method. Can anyone tell whats wrong?

Comment: I guess you need `#/` before the route for eg `ui-sref="#/login"` http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Comment: Don't use `index.html` as your home template file. Also,  set your "otherwise" url to `/`

Comment: don't use index.html as in it shouldn't be called index.html? @Phil

Comment: @Clyde Lobo Please read the link provided by yourself carefully. The # is added on generated href instead of ui-sref.

Comment: @MtTofuu index.html is normally the landing page that loads before angular. Maybe you can try putting `template: ''` if you don't need to replace anything in index.html?

Answer (score 2):

On one side, you should separate your main view from your index.

And, on the other side, your code is not working because this part of the code is wrong:

```
app.config('$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

//redirect if the router is unspecified
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
//home router where all the posts are displayed
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
})

//the login router
.state('login',{
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'loginController'
});

});
```

You forgot the `[]`'s.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    //redirect if the router is unspecified
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
    //home router where all the posts are displayed
        .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    //the login router
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    });

}]);
```

But with that code your main menu won't dissapear.

Here's a snippet with a better approach:

```js
var app = angular.module("secret", ["ui.router"]);

//TO DO: THIS NEEDS TO BE COMPLETED
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    //redirect if the router is unspecified
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/init');

    $stateProvider
    //home router where all the posts are displayed
        .state('init', {
        url: '/init',
        templateUrl: 'init.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    //the login router
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    });

}]);

//service to be used by other controllers
app.factory('posts', [function() {
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };

    return o;

}]);

//the controller for the login router
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

//the controller for the post controller
app.controller('postController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'posts', function($scope, $stateParams, posts) {

}]);

//main controller
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts) {

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<body ng-app="secret">

  <!--Injected View in here-->
  <div ui-view> </div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="init.html">
    <div id="mainBar">
      <div id="mainBarWrapper">
        <div>
          <ul id="navBar">
            <li><a ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>
            <li>Sort
              <ul class="subMenu">
                <li>thing1</li>
                <li>thing2</li>
                <li>thing3</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Schools
              <ul class="subMenu">
                <li>thing1</li>
                <li>thing2</li>
                <li>thing3</li>
                <li>thing4</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="login.html">
    <h1>Login page</h1>
  </script>
</body>
```

PS: I'd recommend you to use latest AngularJS and UI-Router versions.

**EDIT 1**:

All paths are relative to the place you load them, in this case, `index.html`. So that's your base path. As I can't have files in here,  what I did in the code snippet was to add the template between `<script>` tags. You can see them below the `ui-view`directive. Those are 2 templates.

You should always maintain your views separated in templates files, that way everything has order and makes easier bugfixes and maintainence.

Usually inside templates folder:

```
|--index.html
|--templates/
    |--- init.html
    |--- login.html
```

Then you change the `templateUrl` to: `templates/init.html` and `templates/login.html` to the other state.

Comment: for some reason the [] still does not work for me. I was following this tutorial. Can you tell me for the templateUrl what is the path relative to?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, edited my answer to answer your comment and add a bit more of information.